# Replace value in "key: value" statement, but only on first occurence of the key in the file

Tags: text-processing, sed, yaml

I have a yml file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: url
    username:test
    password: testpwd
api:
  security:
    username:foo
    password: foopwd
```

I want to update only the first occurrence or username and password using the command line on a Linux machine so that it looks like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: url
    username:toto
    password: totopsw
api:
  security:
    username:foo
    password: foopwd
```

when i try :

```
sed -i -e 's!^\(\s*username:\)[^"]*!\1toto!' test.yml
```

he change all usernames

Comment: Since the file is specifically a YAML file, would `yq` (a wrapper around `jq`) be acceptable, or are you purely looking for text processing solutions? (A `yq`-based solution would work whether `spring` or `api` was first; conversely, a text processing solution would work regardless of the section name.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is longer, here is an `awk`-based solution that processes it line-wise:

```
awk '/^[[:space:]]+username/ && !u_chng{sub(/:.+$/,": toto"); u_chng=1}
     /^[[:space:]]+password/ && !p_chng{sub(/:.+$/,": totospw"); p_chng=1} 1' input.yml
```

This will check each line whether it starts with `username` or `password`, respectively. If so, and the associated flags `u_chng` and `p_chng` are not yet set, it sets the value after the `:` to your new desired one and sets the respective flag so that any further occurrences of these keywords are disregarded.

Result:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: url
    username: toto
    password: totospw
api:
  security:
    username:foo
    password: foopwd
```

Note that if you use an `awk` implementation that doesn't understand character classes (`[[:space:]]`), change

```
/^[[:space:]]+username/
```

to

```
/^[ \t]+username/
```

Comment: Are there `awk` implementations that don't support `[[:space:]]`? Those are really old and part of [POSIX BREs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), I would be very curious to know if you have come across awk flavors that don't support them.

Comment: @terdon, ThomasDickey [added classes support to `mawk` over 10 years ago](https://invisible-island.net/mawk/CHANGES.html#t20090727), but Debian has not switched to that one for `mawk` until very recently. On Ubuntu 18.04, mawk is the default awk and doesn't support POSIX character classes.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas huh. I had assumed they would have been part of its internal regex engine from day one. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Another `sed` alternative:

```
sed '1,/username/{/username/ s/:.*/:toto/};
     1,/password/{/password/ s/:.*/:totopsw/}' infile
```

`1,/regex/` start from the first line up-to first line that matched with given *`regex`* (here it's `username` string), change the "username"; doing the same for "password" part.

Answer (score 4):

If your file is small enough to fit into memory, you can try reading the entire thing as a single record. That way, `sed` will only make the substitution for the first time it sees the pattern on the "line" (record):

```
$ sed -Ez 's/(username:)[^\n]*/\1toto/; s/(password:)[^\n]*/\1totopsw/' file.yaml 
spring:
  datasource:
    url: url
    username:toto
    password:totopsw
api:
  security:
    username:foo
    password: foopwd
```

To make the change in the original file, just add `-i`:

```
sed -i -Ez 's/(username:)[^\n]*/\1toto/; s/(password:)[^\n]*/\1totopsw/' file.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

With `gnu awk`

```
awk -F '^\\s+|:' '
  BEGIN {
    a["username"] = "toto"
    a["password"] = "totopsw"
  }
  ($2 in a) {
    sub(/:.*/, ": " a[$2])
    delete a[$2]
  };1
' file
```

- set fields separator to be colon or a run of whitespace
- initilaize array a with keywords to search for n their corresponding replacemens.
- after every successful search-n-replace operation , delte the key.

Answer (score 1):

if a `bash` script is valid, you coud use the `sed` `quit`  command:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -E '
    # If we find an username
    /username/ {

        # make the sobstitution of the username
        s/^([[:space:]]*username:)/\1toto/g

        n # Take the next line with the password

        # Sobstitute the password
        s/^([[:space:]]*password:).*$/\1totopw/g

        q1 # Quit after the first match
    }
' test.yml > new_test.yml

# How many line we have taken
len_line=$(sed -n '$=' new_test.yml)

# write the other line
sed "1,${len_line}d" test.yml >> new_test.yml

# rename all the file
rm -f test.yml
mv new_test.yml test.yml
```